Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Bitcoin Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Is it safe to keep a compromised private key in my wallet?
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)




Cant click send on Multibit
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)




What are the specific problems that Virtual Currency is solving? (in the Banking system, economics, and finance )
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)




How is it possible that webservers with deterministic wallets can produce public keys without knowing the underlying private key?
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)




how to stop bitcoin transfers from unknown parties?
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)




is there a litecoin wallet website that does NOT store your private key serverside?
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)




Does an increase in hash/s decrease the time it takes to obtain a block or does it increase the possibilities of solving one?
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)




What does the US government do with seized coins?
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)




How exactly can I generate a transaction id?
Net Score: -6 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 6)




Lost my BTC, though my wallet is still available
Net Score: -6 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 6)




I think the SE has declined a bit since last year. There appears to be a lot of new users in the community that don't bother following the SE format - they ask questions that have been answered, use answers as they would comments or forum replies and so forth.

Perhaps we should downvote questions more aggressively, as Jeff Atwood proposed in a SE-Blog article in 2011.

We also have a serious problem with people flagging answers because they're incorrect. That's what downvoting is for, people.

I think we could do better with tagging. We have a bunch of poor tags, quite a few tags that are missing descriptions and even when new poster's questions are edited, the tags often are not properly adjusted.
As the tags are important for the selection of related questions and making questions more discernible, that might be an area that would yield good reward for any work input.

I wonder if there is value in generalizing the topic from Bitcoins to cryptocoins, and having Bitcoins as just one (albeit the most popular) tag. In terms of usefulness to the e community, I think it may serve a longer and more meaningful lifespan if Bitcoins were considered just one component of a larger community.
